# Issue with connect-mongo, passport & passport-local-mongoose with session not persisting

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, passport.js

Trying to save session and have the functionality of req.isAuthenticated(), req.user etc etc but not getting it to work.

Session is not persisting and just not working in general for some reason.

**app.ts**
https://pastebin.com/yGvUZhud

```
Some Code
```

**routes.ts**
https://pastebin.com/8Q2h1hsK

```
Some Code
```

**controller.ts**
https://pastebin.com/9iU6iHn9

```
Some Code
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found that I needed to call passport.authenticate as middle-ware to the route and had to do route chaining for it to work correctly!

```
app.route('/authenticate')
            .post(passport.authenticate('local'))
            .post((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
                try {
                    console.log(chalk.cyanBright('Request from: ') + chalk.yellowBright(req.originalUrl));
                    console.log(chalk.cyanBright('Request type: ') + chalk.yellowBright(req.method));

                    next();
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(chalk.redBright(error));
                }
            }, this.authenticationController.authenticate);
```